# Inverse functions and tangent line

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse

Let $f(x) = \frac14x^3 + 12x + 6$ and let $y = f^{-1}(x)$ be the inverse function of $f$. Determine the $x$-coordinates of the two points on the graph of the inverse function where the tangent line is perpendicular to the straight line $y = -24x - 32$.

Need help on how to do this, if anyone could show me it would be highly appreciated.

I calculated the derivative to be $\frac34x^2 + 12$. From here do I find the inverse of the derivative and the inverse of the straight line and set them equal to each other to find the $x$-coordinates, or am I supposed to do something else to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Questions regarding homework assignments are more than welcome, provided that they briefly explain the problem you are trying to solve—do not post your entire assignment verbatim, explain what you tried and where you're stuck (showing your work is a good idea) and don't ask for complete solutions to the problem; we're not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

$y = \frac 1 4 x^3 + 12x + 6$

$L = -24x - 32$

$P$ is a line that is perpendicular to $L$.

The slope of a perpendicular is the negative of the multiplicative inverse, that is: $$\frac{dP} {dx} = -(\frac {dL} {dx})^{-1} = -\frac{dx} {dL}$$

To solve the problem we want $y$ where:
 $$\underbrace{\frac {dx} {dy}}_{\text{slope of the inverse}} = \underbrace{\frac {dP} {dx}}_{\text{Slope of a perpendicular}}$$
 $$\frac {dx} {dy} = -\frac {dx} {dL}$$
 $$\frac {dy} {dx} = -\frac {dL} {dx}$$
 $$\frac {3} {4} x^2 + 12 = -(-24)$$
 $$x = \pm 4$$

Then just find the corresponding $y$ values, which are the $x$ values of the inverse function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Apply the chain rule and implicit differentiation to find the gradient. If you have the graph with equation $y=\operatorname{f}^{-1}(x)$ then it also has the equation $\operatorname{f}(y)=x$.